# Javascript automatic server request stops the previous request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a javascript code that send request to server for every sec and the same code i have in another page to send new request to server for every sec the problem is after starting the second automatic request the first request is not submitting every second.
Please help me....

Comment: Please check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please post yotr code, otherwise your question becomes too broad to answer (i.e: a lot of things could be causing your problem)

Comment: Please look into my code and give me some advice.